Если в if использую кириллицу всегда идет else
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
using namespace std;

 int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
string sim; 
cout << "Да или нет?" << endl;
cin >> sim;
if (sim == "Да") {
    cout << "получилось";
}
else cout << "не получилось";
}


Кодировки! Попробуйте выводить введенное (cout << sim) и посмотрите, что получается...

Всё решилось, просто string не принимала кирилицу, задал ей
locale::global(locale("")); потом  wcin. imbue (locale(".866")); и wcout. imbue ( locale(".1251")) ;
